# ViewState, null и злость

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

```
 protected void btnsearch_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     ViewState["poisk"] = TextBox1.Text;
 }

 protected void BindGridView()
 {

     if (ViewState["poisk"] != null)
     {
         Label7.Text = ViewState["poisk"].ToString(); 
     }
     else
     {
         Label7.Text = "Empty search string";
     }
}
```

Всегда `ViewState["poisk"] = null`. Как исправить?

UPD: Ход событий:

1. `BindGridView` ( `ViewState = null`)
2. `btnsearch_Cllick1` ( `ViewState = string`)
3. `BindGridView` ( `ViewState = null`, но должно быть `string`)

Comment: ViewState так не готовят, вам нужен Session скорее всего.

Comment: Этот вертолет не полетит - суть в моем непонимании алгоритма заргузки страницы. Но Ваш вариант тоже был достаточно близко и сам по-себе интересен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ мне рассказали в чате, но, думаю, будет не лишним добавить сюда для тех, кто столкнется с схожей проблемой.

Было:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (!IsPostBack)
         {
             BindGridView();
         }
     }
```

Таким образом, проблема в нарушеной очередности взаимодействия между функциями.
Ключ к пониманию вопроса: [тыц](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

код от @PashaPash:

```
protected void btnsearch_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
      ViewState["poisk"] = TextBox1.Text; BindGridView(); 
}
```